# Can't click on button with Selenium on Bumble with xpath

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently trying to make a Bumble bot that auto logs in and start swiping, However it seems that none of the elements on the website are clickable or can be located with xpath. Specifically I am trying to click the Continue button for accepting cookies but xpath can't find it at all

Here is the code:

```python
from time import sleep as wait
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

import random

class BumbleBot():

    def __init__(self, Username, Password):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        self.Username = Username
        self.Password = Password

    def LaunchBumble(self):

        wait(1)

        self.driver.get("https://bumble.com/app")
        self.driver.maximize_window()

        wait(2)

        self.BumbleLogin()

        wait(15)

    def CookieAccept(self):
        try:
            #WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="notice"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/button'))).click()
            CookieButton = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="notice"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/button')
            CookieButton.click()
        except:
            print("No cookies")

    def BumbleLogin(self):
        self.CookieAccept()
        
        wait(15.5)`
```

I've tried using the absolute xpath and even that doesn't work. What is going on and why isn't it letting select and click buttons?

There seems to be an iframe of some sort too for the cookie consent button taking up the entire webpage.